# Сложной цикл или функция

Tags: python, функции, циклы, for

Не знаю как правильно реализовать сложную задачу цикл.
Задача общими словами то: ищем сессии с событием А, выделяем все события с сессиями С
ищем позицию события А в сессии С
ищем событие Б после позиции события А
нашли событие Б – записали
У меня есть два датафрейма.

В одном лежать id сессий
df1

```
sessionId
668     bcd153f8-6c76-4d57-ae96-8c8c79c3238e
3785    6b188d67-b5a0-4986-907e-6f49cfb63d73
5650    62555187-2dae-47fd-9a51-f462b369b994
14846   8b7b3f23-cf5b-43f1-bb41-eb2c9cbfda22
26955   6a831820-582b-498b-832e-f3aa29709491
```

Второй Dataframe со всеми событиями(общий)
df2
[image: df2]
Нужно отфильтровать df2 по id session
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее найти событие,например (event=searchButton and text==qr) из отфильтрованного df и взять данные которые произошли после нашего события не включая его.
[image: df3]
Эти события нужно запихнуть в отдельный Dataframe5.
И проделать это события с каждой сессией из df1 и объединять с предыдущем выводом.
На выходе должен получиться один объединённый dataframe5.

В ручную я могу это сделать, но таблица большая и на одну таблицу уйдет месяц. Помогите автоматизировать процесс.
Я пробовал написать цикл. Но он не работает.

```
i= []
for index, row in df1.itertuples(): #Берем все сессии df1 и прогоняем через общий df2
    print(row)
    for pps in row: # выводим из df2  все события с конкретным idses
        if pss['sessionId']=='044844f0-0e36-4db1-8104-011690bf08cf': #
            print(pss['sessionId'])
            for ttr in for:  # выводим только те события которые произошли после нужно действия
                if text==quizFind   # Тут мне нужно взять все сессии после события и поместить их в отдельный df3 
            i.append(ttr)
            И так пройтись по каждой сесии из df1.
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: в ваших примерах данных нет совпадающих сессий и кроме этого непонятно как должен выглядеть результат

Comment: Спасибо, постарался исправить.

Comment: как должен выглядеть результат для приведенных в вопросе входных данных?? Как мы, по-вашему, должны трактовать "... обобрать все сессии которые произошли после __определенного события__ ..." ? ;)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Первый раз сюда пишу)) извините за безграмотность и корявость запроса. Вы очень классные.

Comment: в выложенных на Google Drive данных нет столбца `text` - я сдаюсь. Желаю удачи! ;)

Comment: Ну если что, то я все исправил))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша задача описана очень непонятно.
Накидал тут код который как мне кажется облегчит вам задачу.

```py
import pandas as pd

sessions_df = pd.read_csv("stackOverflow/sessionsSort/session.csv")
data_df = pd.read_csv("stackOverflow/sessionsSort/file1.csv")
# Фильтруем данные, что бы не обрабатывать не нужные
filtered_df = data_df[data_df["sessionId"].isin(sessions_df["sessionId"].unique())]
# Группируем данные что бы работать с каждой сессией отдельно
grouped_data = filtered_df.groupby("sessionId")


def search_data(event: str, text: str, df: pd.DataFrame):
    # Эта функция ищет нужные ивенты
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    # содержит строки с нужными ивентами
    filtered = df[df.apply(lambda x: x['event'] == event and x['text'] == text, axis=1)]
    print(f"Найдено событий: {filtered.shape[0]}")
    # дальше можно сохранять и как то обрабатывать датафрейм.


# Итерируемся по датафреймам. 
# Здесь item[0] это sessionId а item[1] это датафрейм с данными по этой сессии.
for item in grouped_data:
    print(f"processing sessionId: {item[0]}")
    # Можно либо сохранить датафрейм или использовать доп функцию что бы как то обработать его.
    search_data("searchButton", "qr", item[1])
```

Пути к файлам только замените на свои.
Это скелет, если не понятно что делать то давайте разделим вашу задачу на несколько частей что бы можно было это имплементировать.
И постарайтесь в описании задачи использовать говорящие названия.
Так же потратьте время на структурное описание алгоритма.
Например:

Имеется:

- data_df - датафрейм с сессиями (файл file1.csv)
- sessions_df - датафрейм с сессиями которые необходимо обработать (файл session.csv)

1. Нужно отфильтровать данные из data_df. Нужны только строки в которых колонка sessionId совпадает с одним из sessionId указанных в sessions_df.
2. Поместить строки соответствующие одному sessionId в отдельный датафрейм для каждого sessionId
3. и так далее.

Comment: Спасибо большое)) в след раз буду лучше формировать запрос)